# OpenGL need to upgrade 14.10

Tags: 14.04, drivers, steam, opengl

So this is my first time on `Ubuntu` so i have no idea what i am doing.
I just know that windows 10 sucks with the updates every day and disc 100%.
Anyway i installed Steam (I am a `Dota` player) and when i tried to launch Dota i got this error:

```
 Required OpenGL extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects is not supported.Please update your OpenDL driver.
```

I have no idea how to fix this i used dell system detect for all my drivers but i can't install any drivers on Ubuntu.Please help and explain it as simply as you can.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update OpenGL.  In a terminal enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa mesa-vdpau-drivers
```

([source](http://blog.amet13.name/2015/09/dota2-reborn.html))